# Why does my linear search isn't linearly taking more time with regards to the array size

Tags: c++, binary-search

I was trying to benchmark binary search vs linear search. I'm using `C++`.

Here is how I implemented my benchmark:

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
using namespace std;

class Solution {
public:
    int search(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        int low = 0;
        int high = nums.size() - 1;

        while (low <= high) {
            int mid = (low + high) / 2;
            if (target > nums[mid]) {
                low = mid+1;
            } else if (target < nums[mid]) {
                high = mid-1;
            } else {
                return mid;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }

    int naiveSearch(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        for(int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++) {
            if(nums[i] == target) {
                return i;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }
};

int main() {
    Solution sol;
    for(int n = 1000; n <= 10000000; n += 10000) {
        // Random target, always gonna be in the array
        int target = rand()%n+1;

        vector<int> nums(n);
        iota(nums.begin(), nums.end(), 1);

        auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        sol.search(nums, target);
        auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(stop - start);
        cout << n << "," << duration.count() << ",Binary" << endl;

        start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        sol.naiveSearch(nums, target);
        stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(stop - start);
        cout << n << "," << duration.count() << ",Naive" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I then copied everything in a `data.csv` and plotted it in `python` with this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', names=['Size', 'Time', 'Method'])

binary_data = data[data['Method'] == 'Binary']
naive_data = data[data['Method'] == 'Naive']

plt.plot(binary_data['Size'], binary_data['Time'], label='Binary')
plt.plot(naive_data['Size'], naive_data['Time'], label='Naive')

plt.xlabel('Input size')
plt.ylabel('Time (microseconds)')
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

I expected a linear increase in time for the `Naive` method but I had this graph:
[image]

I ran without optimizer `g++ -O0 -o output_file.exe hello_world.cpp` in case my optimizer was doing something shady but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Benchmarking with `-O0` is pretty pointless and if you enable optimizations, the compiler will optimize away the function calls that you want to measure because nothing depends on their return values and they have no side effects.

Comment: It's not pointless, OP is clearly trying to learn how search works and seeing with benchmarks that theory and practice aligns is one of the most important things when learning CS.

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows -- you missed the point: the comment is about benchmarking **without optimizations** which is, indeed, pretty pointless. The trick is in writing the code so that turning optimizations **on** won't result in optimizing away all of the searches.

Comment: I get that but this might be too complicated for someone learning the basics

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows -- it's hard to learn the basics when your program gives silly results. Don't talk down to people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very interesting question. The answer is that when you generate the `target`, you only generate small numbers.

One of the common reasons for getting only small numbers with rand() is that it generates random numbers within a limited range, between `0` and [`RAND_MAX`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/RAND_MAX) (inclusive). The value of this weird `RAND_MAX` is an implementation-defined constant, and it must be at least `32767`. This means that the maximum value that can be generated by rand() is `RAND_MAX`, and the range of values is from `0` to `RAND_MAX`. For some systems, `RAND_MAX` might be relatively small (on mine it's `32767`).

Therefore, all of your searches finish really quickly (after at most `32767` executions).

A proper benchmark with a proper random generation would yield this:
[image: Proper Benchmark Plot]

Here is how you can know what your `RAND_MAX` is:

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << RAND_MAX << '\n';
}
```

And here is proof that on some configurations, `RAND_MAX` is big:

[image]

Comment: How can I know what my `RAND_MAX` is?

Comment: You can literally print `RAND_MAX`

Comment: For this purpose a better method would be to do `int target = (int)((rand()/(RAND_MAX + 1.0)*n) + 1;`. Not a very good random number, but good enough for testing the algorithms.

Comment: My bad, wrote the answer too fast. Good point.